# shutil.move - Cannot move directory into itself... (Python)

Tags: python, directory, move, mkdir, shutil

It's late night for me and I'm banging my head against the wall as to why I can't figure this out.

Trying to split a directory with 100,000 folders (directories) into 4 subfolders with 25,000 folders/directories in each sub_directory.

Here is the code I have:

```
import os
import shutil
import alive_progress
from alive_progress import alive_bar
import time

# Set the directory you want to separate
src_dir = r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\base'

# Set the number of directories you want in each subdirectory
num_dirs_per_subdir = 25000

# Set the base name for the subdirectories
subdir_base_name = '25k-Split'

# Calculate the number of subdirectories needed
num_subdirs = len(os.listdir(src_dir)) // num_dirs_per_subdir


# Iterate over the subdirectories
for i in range(num_subdirs):
    # Create the subdirectory path
    subdir_path = os.path.join(src_dir, f'{subdir_base_name}_{i}')
    # Create the subdirectory
    os.mkdir(subdir_path)
    # Get the directories to move
    dirs_to_move = os.listdir(src_dir)[i*num_dirs_per_subdir:(i+1)*num_dirs_per_subdir]
    # Iterate over the directories to move
    with alive_bar(1000, force_tty=True) as bar:
        for directory in dirs_to_move:
            # Construct the source and destination paths
            src_path = os.path.join(src_dir, directory)
            dst_path = os.path.join(subdir_path, directory)
            bar()
            # Move the directory
            shutil.move(src_path, dst_path)
            bar()
```

I of course receive the following error:

`Cannot move a directory 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\base\25k-Split_0' into itself 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\base\25k-Split_0\25k-Split_0'`

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This program should work as expected, **if** you only run it once.  But if you run it twice, then the subdir `25k-Split_0` will already exist, and so it is treated as "just another file to be moved".

Comment: You should exclude subdirs from `dirs_to_move`.  (Which really should be named `files_to_move`)

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 bugs:

1. You don't calculate the number of directories needed correctly.

   Change

   ```
   num_subdirs = len(os.listdir(src_dir)) // num_dirs_per_subdir
   ```

   to

   ```
   num_subdirs = len(os.listdir(src_dir)) // num_dirs_per_subdir + 1
   ```

   If you have 1 directory, and want 25,000 directories per subdirectory. How many subdirectories do you need? 1. Not 0.
2. You need to check if the subdirectory already exists:

   ```
   # Create the subdirectory path
   subdir_path = os.path.join(src_dir, f'{subdir_base_name}_{i}')
   if os.path.exists(subdir_path):
       raise RuntimeError(f"{subdir_path} already exists")
   # Create the subdirectory
   os.mkdir(subdir_path)
   ```
3. You should give the target directory to `shutil.move`:

   ```
   shutil.move(src_path, subdir_path)
   ```
4. You recalculate the directory list every time, which includes the subdirectories:

   ```
   # outside loop
   directories = os.listdir(src_dir)
   # ...
   dirs_to_move = directories[i*num_dirs_per_subdir:(i+1)*num_dirs_per_subdir]
   ```

I believe issues #2 & 4 are the main problem.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, have made these changes - however, it successfully creates the directories but only fills the first 2 with 25k folders and then creates several empty folders leaving 50k+ folders in the base directory.

Comment: @KEEPBUSY See issue #4, fix it and tell me if it works

Comment: What if I wanted to split it into 1/4's or % instead of a hard 25k so it can be used with any number as now I am weirdly at 99,983 folders.

Comment: Sorry I also don't really understand where the snippet from step 4 should be placed in the code if you could please help...

Comment: It's telling me directories is not defined...

Comment: `directories == os.listdir(src_dir)` goes outside all loops (for example, after the line `num_subdirs = ...`), `dirs_to_move = ...` replaces the same line in your code in the first loop

Comment: Yes I understand that, but if placed there it's telling me that "directories is not defined" in both of those changes/additions... are you sure it shouldn't be changed from "directories" to something else? Another variable/name?

Comment: # outside loop
directories == os.listdir(src_dir)

^ directories is not defined.

directories[i*num_dirs_per_subdir:(i+1)*num_dirs_per_subdir]

^ directories is not defined.

Comment: @KEEPBUSY oh it should be `=` not `==`. That's a typo

Comment: @KEEPBUSY my bad, typo fixed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

> dirs_to_move = os.listdir(src_dir)[...

You keep fetching the directory list each time you go through the outer loop `range(num_subdirs)`. After you handle the first subdir, the second iteration of the loop also gets the subdir you just created..

Delete the line above from inside the first loop and calculate directories to move outside the loops only once. Then index into it to get the list of dirs to move without refetching the directory list again, like this:

```
all_dirs = os.listdir(src_dir)

# Iterate over the subdirectories
for i in range(num_subdirs):
   dir_index = i * num_dirs_per_subdir
   dirs_to_move = all_dirs[dir_index : dir_index+num_dirs_per_subdir]
   ...
```

Your logic doesn't work if number of directories doesn't divide into `num_dirs_per_subdir` exactly. Here is how you can fix that:

```
   start_index = i*num_dirs_per_subdir
   end_index = start_index + num_dirs_per_subdir
   if end_index > len(all_dirs):
       dirs_to_move = all_dirs[start_index:]
   else:
       dirs_to_move = all_dirs[start_index : end_index]
   ...
```

Comment: What if I wanted to split it into 1/4's or % instead of a hard 25k so it can be used with any number as now I am weirdly at 99,983 folders.

Comment: @KEEPBUSY I updated my answer to include what you are asking

Comment: what would the code be following what you've provided?

After ...end_index]

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to coding :)

Comment: thank you also for all of your help! i think that's the final piece of the puzzle :) let me know...

Comment: @KEEPBUSY You're welcome. What I showed should replace the one line starting with `dirs_to_move =` in the first loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work! I created 10000 folders to test on as was worried to test on my actual directory. I changed 25000 to 2500 and the result was the base directory - all folders within it disappeared aside from one new folder that was aptly named accordingly for the first split folder. However, entering that folder there are only 500 folders inside. I have no idea where the other 9500 went...

Comment: NEVERMIND I GOT IT! THANK YOU! SO MUCH!

Comment: @KEEPBUSY sort the directory list, like this: `all_dirs = sorted(os.listdir(src_dir))`

Comment: Got it thanks for that! Unfortunately, I didn't realize, but there is always an extra folder created that remains empty... See here: https://imgur.com/a/dXMoyJ8 - this is a 55 directory folder split by 5's... Any idea how to make sure this extra folder isn't created? I was thinking also maybe it's better to instead of splitting by X number of subdirectories, to be able to either give a number X or a % value of the main directory (if you know how!) THANK YOU AGAIN! <3 Can I also contact you for private tutoring or projects?

Comment: @KEEPBUSY hmmm my proposed solution shouldn't create an extra empty folder. I think I would need to see the whole code to find the issue. Sure, feel free to reach out for private tutoring.

Comment: Could really use your help. Got frustrated and reverted back, made, changes, and VScode crashed so this is the code I have - close to what it should be, but yes the index portion ended up creating 500k empty folders with randomly placed subdirectories... could really use you! https://controlc.com/fe0526ac (password: drip)

Comment: I also have no idea how to contact you if you could leave an email or link to Telegram or something outside of stackoverflow that would be appreciated :)

Comment: @Embrah - Here is also a version that I got to work, but creates an extra empty folder... https://controlc.com/18f64081 (password: drip) - let me know! Thanks!

Comment: @KEEPBUSY on line 90, get rid of the `+ 1`, that's why you get an extra empty subdir if the total number of dirs is an integer multiple of `num_dirs_per_subdir`. If `num_subdirs` is calculated as 0 (which means `num_dirs_per_subdir` > `len(os.listdir(src_dir))`), then you can set it to 1. Also, replace line 117 with the 6 lines of code I have in my comment starting with `start_index = ...`